# JavaScript: forEach function is not specifying the item to count in iteration loop

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function for a game called TwilioQuest. The function neeps to loop through each item in the `freightItems` array (already defined by TwilioQuest) and count each time the item `'contraband'` is noticed. I created an array after the function to test the code.

The problem I'm having is that the function doesn't seem to be able to discriminate between the item 'contraband' and any other item. When the `contrabandCount` is returned, it displays `"5"` instead of the expected "2". Can anyone help me understand where I went wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
function scan(freightItems) {
  let contrabandCount = 0;
  freightItems.forEach(function(freightItems) {
    if ('contraband') contrabandCount++;
  });
  return contrabandCount;
}

const numItems = scan(['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers',
  'contraband'
]);
console.log('Number of "contraband": ' + numItems)
```

Comment: Your issue is with: `if ('contraband')` as you need to check if `freightItem` (the argument in your forEach callback) equals `'contraband'`

Comment: have you read [the documentation on `Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to compare the `freightItems` value to "contraband"

```js
freightItems.forEach(function(freightItem) {
  if(freightItem === 'contraband')
    contrabandCount++
})
```

Comment: same thoughts only you was quicker upvoting answer.

Comment: Thank you Zartaj and aviboy! This makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function scan(freightItems) {
  let contrabandCount = 0;
  freightItems.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry == 'contraband') {
      contrabandCount++;
    }
  });

  return contrabandCount;
}

const numItems = scan(['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers',
  'contraband'
]);
console.log('Number of "contraband": ' + numItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter method is all you need

```js
const numItems = ['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband'];

var filtered = numItems.filter(x => x == 'contraband');
console.log('Number of "contraband": ' + filtered.length);
```

You can use this sintax if you want, remember compare freightItems with 'contraband'

```js
function scan(freightItems) {
  let contrabandCount = 0;
  freightItems.forEach((freightItems) => {
    'contraband' === freightItems ? contrabandCount++ : 0;
  });
  return contrabandCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an improved **Syntax** :

With `forEach` :

```
function scan(searchabelItem, freightItems, contrabandCount = 0) {
    freightItems.forEach((value) => value === searchabelItem && contrabandCount++)
    return contrabandCount;
}
```

With `filter` :

```
 function scan(searchabelItem, freightItems, contrabandCount = 0) {
        freightItems.filter((value) => value === searchabelItem && contrabandCount++)
        return contrabandCount;
    }
```